# Blinking effect with fadeIn/fadeOut CABasicAnimation

Tags: objective-c, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I am trying to animate a layer to indefinitely blink (fade in and out, until the isBlinking property is switched to false), my attempt is the following, but it does not seem to be working properly, I can observe a bit of a glitch every couple of blinks. I also want the layer to fade in to be fully opaque when the property is set to false, so that there are not any drastic sudden opacity changes, but for some reason my code is not working for doing that either.

```
var isBlinking: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if !isBlinking {
            layer.removeAllAnimations()
            let fadeIn = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            fadeIn.toValue = 1
            fadeIn.duration = 1
            layer.addAnimation(fadeIn, forKey: nil)
            return
        }

        let fadeOut = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeOut.fromValue = 1
        fadeOut.toValue = 0.1
        fadeOut.duration = 1

        let fadeIn = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeIn.fromValue = 0.1
        fadeIn.toValue = 1
        fadeIn.duration = 1
        fadeIn.beginTime = 1

        let group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.duration = 2
        group.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        group.animations = [fadeOut, fadeIn]

        layer.addAnimation(group, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any advice or input in swift or obj-c. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for your fromValues and toValues need to be NSNumber

```
    fadeIn.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.1)
    fadeIn.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
```